# arithmetic of theorem Fundament

Tags: java

I need to write program that the user will insert a number
and than it will print all the prime number that if you duplicate them you will get the number and how many times you have the number/.
cant use array!
example :
if you insert 100
 ( 2*2*5*5)
the input need to be :

> 2 2
>
> 5 2

I did this code
this will tell me the prime number but not how many times

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class Mesima3coral {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    int n = myScanner.nextInt () ;
    int number = 2 ;

    while (number <=n) {
        int count = 1 ;
        boolean isPrime = true ;
        int divisor = 2 ;
        while (divisor*divisor <=number & isPrime) {
            if (number%divisor == 0) {
                isPrime = false ;
            }
            divisor = divisor +1 ;
        }
        if (isPrime & n%number==0) {
            System.out.println(number);




        }
        number=number+1 ;


    } } }
```

Comment: You need to actually modify `n` or a copy of `n`: Make the last `if` a `while` loop. In the loop divide `n` by `number` and count how many times this worked. Move the `println` after the loop and print `number` and count.

Comment: any way you can show me how to do it ?

Comment: You should try it yourself first.

Comment: while (isPrime & n%number==0) {
    count =  n/number ;
   }
   number=number+1 ;
   
   System.out.print (number );
   System.out.println(count);

Answer (score 0):

Replace last `if` by something like

```
count = 0;
while (isPrime & n%number==0) {
    n /= number;
    ++count;
}
if (count > 0) {
    System.out.print(number);
    System.out.println(" " + count);
}
```